# How to make prepended elements to overflow window on top?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list of elements. Сomments, to be more specific. Button «Load previous» **prepends** previous comments to the list. But when I prepend previous comments it moves other comments down instead of overflowing on top. I want new prepended comments to overflow window on top. I tried to use `overflow-anchor` property in different variations, but in didn't help. Is there any way to implement this behavior without using JavaScript?

```
<button class="add">Load previous</button>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.add').on("click", function() {
    $('ul').prepend(`
        <li class="red">1</li>
        <li class="red">2</li>
        <li class="red">3</li>
        <li class="red">4</li>
        <li class="red">5</li>
        <li class="red">6</li>
        <li class="red">7</li>
        <li class="red">8</li>
        <li class="red">9</li>
  `);
});
```

Comment: Please provide your CSS and the markup surrounding this. How the list is positioned and contained is important.

Comment: @AK why? Neither of those would appear to be relevant to this.

Comment: i know you need non-js approach but i would suggest just scroll to bottom after prepending it will take hardly 1 line of code as you already have js included.....